# ServiceStack ServerEventsClient auto-reconnect

Tags: servicestack

I am using the ServerEventsClient for server side events to clients. Currently if I shutdown the server the client doesn't automatically reconnect later when it is available again.

How do I make it automatically try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Our tests do show that the `ServerEventsClient` does auto-reconnect when the App Server is restarted, here's a simple test we use:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient("http://localhost:11001", "home")
{
    OnConnect = ctx => "OnConnect: {0}".Print(ctx.Channel),
    OnCommand = msg => "OnCommand: {0}".Print(msg.Data),
    OnException = ex => "OnException: {0}".Print(ex.Message),
    OnMessage = msg => "OnMessage: {0}".Print(msg.Data),
    OnHeartbeat = () => "OnHeartbeat".Print()
};

client.Handlers["chat"] = (source, msg) =>
{
    "Received Chat: {0}".Print(msg.Data);
};

await client.Connect();
```

And the logs showing the ServerEventClient auto-reconnecting when the AppServer it's connected to is restarted:

```
OnConnect: 
OnCommand: home@cmd.onJoin {"userId":"-2","isAuthenticated":"false","displayName":"user2","channels":"home","profileUrl":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ServiceStack/Assets/master/img/apps/no-profile64.png"}
OnHeartbeat
Received Chat: home@cmd.chat {"id":1,"fromUserId":"-1","fromName":"user1","message":"1","private":false}
OnMessage: home@cmd.chat {"id":1,"fromUserId":"-1","fromName":"user1","message":"1","private":false}
Received Chat: home@cmd.chat {"id":2,"fromUserId":"-1","fromName":"user1","message":"2","private":false}
OnMessage: home@cmd.chat {"id":2,"fromUserId":"-1","fromName":"user1","message":"2","private":false}
OnHeartbeat
OnHeartbeat
OnException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
OnConnect: 
OnCommand: home@cmd.onJoin {"userId":"-3","isAuthenticated":"false","displayName":"user3","channels":"home","profileUrl":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ServiceStack/Assets/master/img/apps/no-profile64.png"}
Received Chat: home@cmd.chat {"id":1,"fromUserId":"-2","fromName":"user2","message":"1","private":false}
OnMessage: home@cmd.chat {"id":1,"fromUserId":"-2","fromName":"user2","message":"1","private":false}
Received Chat: home@cmd.chat {"id":2,"fromUserId":"-2","fromName":"user2","message":"2","private":false}
OnMessage: home@cmd.chat {"id":2,"fromUserId":"-2","fromName":"user2","message":"2","private":false}
OnHeartbeat
OnHeartbeat
```

If you have code that reproduces the issue please submit it to [ServiceStack's Issue Tracker](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues).